# Error loading Package.dtsx: Failed to load the value property using default persistence

Tags: c#, ssis

I am developing a custom task for SSIS, and must have a property that is of type Dictionary .
When you compile and open a project in the SSIS task apparently funcionona, but when I save the project, close and open again, the error appears:

> Erro  1   Error loading Package.dtsx: Failed to load the value property "DadosGriDataTable" using default persistence.    C:\Temp\teste\Integracao\Integracao\Package.dtsx    1   1
>
> Erro  2   Error loading Package.dtsx: Failed to load task "ICOM Envio 411 Task", type "ICOMEnvio411Task.ICOMEnvio411Task, ICOMEnvio411Task, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=498701fa3ac6a73f". The contact information for this task is "".      C:\Temp\teste\Integracao\Integracao\Package.dtsx    1   1

Follows the code:

```
    public class ICOMEnvio411Task : Task
{
        private Dictionary<string, object> _dadosGriDataTable = null;
        [Category("ICOM Sources")]
        [Description("Dados Grid")]
        public Dictionary<string, object> DadosGriDataTable
        {
            get { return this._dadosGriDataTable; }
            set { this._dadosGriDataTable = value; }
        }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide persistence methods for your objects see [Persisting Custom Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403354.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!
I followed the link and implemented the IDTSComponentPersist and the error did not happen more, but now I can no longer save, the following error occurs:

**Unhandled exception at 0x34F4D143 (msenv.dll) in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000020A.**

Also like to know whether you can debug custom one task?

Thanks!

Comment: Debugging custom tasks is a painful endeavor but can be done. You'll need two instances of Visual Studio running. One with the source code, one with the SSIS package using the component. Set a breakpoint in the SSIS package and then you attach the debugger in the code editor instance to attach to the process in the SSIS instance. There were lots of walkthroughs on it back in 2005-2008 when I last developed custom components but it can be done

Comment: I found the error on the message: **Unhandled exception at 0x34F4D143 (msenv.dll) in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000020A**
How was failing to debug, I had a MessageBox.Show in SaveToXML, event to see if it was right where you can not add this type of message.
About degubar really is a painful puco same, but got as tip!

Thank you!